# Subject throws Section numbering off

Tags: context

compiling this MWE.

```
\starttext

\startchapter[title=chapter 1]
    \startsection[title=Section 1.1]
        \startsubsection[title=Section 1.1.1]
             \subject{a Subject}
        \stopsubsection
        % Another subsection which numbers incorrectly
        \startsubsection[title=Section 1.1.2]
        \stopsubsection
    \stopsection
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

gives me the following result[image: compiled]

Using context version: 2017.06.06 13:22 on windows 7.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this a known issue?

Comment: "Subject" is at the same level as "section". The heads are part, chapter/title, section/subject, subsection/subsubject, etc. So, in order to have a proper structure you need `\subsubsubject{...}` inside of a subsection, not `\subject{...}`. Indeed, making this change to the MWE leads to the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong structure level.  `\subject` is the unnumbered variant of `\section`.  So you want to use `\subsubsubject` (similar to `\subsubsection`.

```
\starttext

\startchapter[title=chapter 1]
  \startsection[title=Section 1.1]
    \startsubsection[title=Section 1.1.1]
      \subsubsubject{a Subject}
    \stopsubsection
    \startsubsection[title=Section 1.1.2]
    \stopsubsection
  \stopsection
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

[image]

You can also make the subsection ignore the counter reset on a higher level (in this case section) but this will also ignore `\section` in addition to `\subject`.

```
\defineresetset[noreset][1,1,1,0][1]
\setuphead[subsection][sectionresetset=noreset]

\starttext

\startchapter[title=chapter 1]
  \startsection[title=Section 1.1]
    \startsubsection[title=Section 1.1.1]
      \subject{a Subject}
    \stopsubsection
    \startsubsection[title=Section 1.1.2]
    \stopsubsection
  \stopsection
  \startsection[title=Section 1.1]
    \startsubsection[title=Section 1.1.1]
      \subject{a Subject}
    \stopsubsection
    \startsubsection[title=Section 1.1.2]
    \stopsubsection
  \stopsection
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: @user137320 If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).